# Vectorise gradient descent without matrix transpose

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I have written below gradient descent in the vectorized form using matrix transpose for logistic regression and it works fine

```
%grad(1) = (1/m)*X(:,1)'*(h-y);
%grad(2:end) = (1/m)*(X(:,2:end)'*(h-y)) + (lambda/m)*theta(2:end);
```

But when I am trying to use it without matrix transpose it gives matrix operation error only when I add `+ (lambda/m)*theta(2:end)` to  `grad(2:end)`

```
%grad(1) = (1/m)*sum((h-y).*X(:,1));
%grad(2:end) = ((1/m)*sum((h-y).*X(:,2:end))) + (lambda/m)*theta(2:end);
```

Comment: It's either MATLAB, or Octave, not both. Which one are you using? Please remove the other tag

Comment: Note: `'` is not transpose, it is the complex conjugate transpose. `.'` is transpose. "It gives an error" is not a problem statement, show us the full error message and a [mcve] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: 飮ఀTesting lrCostFunction() with regularizationerror: lrCostFunction: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 3x1,
 op2 is 3x3)
error: called from
    lrCostFunction at line 67 column 13
    ex3 at line 62 column 9

Comment: this is the error

Comment: actually, I used both .' and ' they both are giving me same result but this not my question I am telling to fix the below code which is without '

Comment: You get an error because by removing the transpose, your math is incorrect. Why do you want to remove the transpose? What advantage does that give you?

Comment: thank you for the response look it works fine when I do not add regularization to it which is (lambda/m)*theta(2:end);  i am trying to do so because it can also be done without using transpose using  and using sum and  .* operation

Comment: There is a reason we want you to pick one of Octave or MATLAB, and not tag both. These are different systems and solutions potentially are different for the two. Tagging both potentially makes the question ambiguous.

Comment: Likely the case is that the result of the first expression is transposed w.r.t. the original code. But I can't say for sure, and thus cannot post an answer, because I don't know what `h` is, what `y` is, what `m` is, what `X` is, or what `lambda` and `theta` are. Wolfie asked you to add a [mcve] to your post. That means that I would be able to copy-paste your code into my MATLAB session and see the error you are seeing. I cannot do that now because the code is not complete. Please complete your post!

Comment: yes sure i will do that

Comment: z = X*theta;
h = sigmoid(z);

Comment: function g = sigmoid(z)
%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid functoon
%   J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
end  X = 5000*400 matrix and y = 5000*1

Comment: Please add updates to the question itself using [edit]. Questions should be completely self-contained and code in comments can't be formatted. Speaking of which, please format your code properly in both your question and your answer. See [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for hints on how to do that. Lastly, if you tag the person you're talking to like @beaker, they'll be notified that you've responded to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I figured it out now it should be

grad(2:end) =  (1/m)*sum((h-y).*X(:,2:end))' + (lambda/m)*theta(2:end);